# How can I find the time of property files gets loaded by Spring

Tags: java, spring, configuration-files, apache-commons

I am replacing the property factory which is used to the load the configuration files with spring. So technically now, my configuration files should be loaded using spring DI via Apache
commons configurations.
So far I have created an Action class and a POJO view class which has the getters and setters for Loadtime, FileModified time, File name etc. The Action has a list of configuration classes injected into the constructor and in the execute method I am looping over the configuration classes creating a simple view object for each one. Then I am setting the value to the my view object which I get from config something like this:

```
 public final String execute() {
    configViewList = new ArrayList<ConfigurationViewObject>();
    if ((this.configurationList != null) && (this.configurationList.size() != 0)) {
        for (PropertiesConfiguration config : configurationList) {
            ConfigurationViewObject view = new ConfigurationViewObject();
            view.setFileName(config.getFileName());
            view.setFileModificationTime(new Date(config.getFile().lastModified()));
            configViewList.add(view);
        }
        return SUCCESS;
    } else {
        addActionError("List is null.");
        return Action.ERROR;
    }
}
```

Well, now I want to find out the load time. Any idea how to find the time when the spring loads the file.I have entirely searched PropertiesConfiguration class and File class if there is any method which gets it for me, however couldn't find any. I would appreciate the much awaited help.

Answer (score 0):

Its very tricky to find this because Spring will never expose this to outside world and thats correct, why would anyone want to know when config file gets loaded?

But still , here is what i would do. Spring config will be loaded when Spring creates loads a class which needs some properties to be set [This is not document officially anywhere but thats how it shld be logically]. Now next part is to find out which class instance needing properties is created first. Again no starighforward way for this but still an appox. way would be to put a `System.currentTimeMillis()` in Class's constructor. So this will give you an appox. time of when property file will be loaded.

Comment: As I mentioned I am replacing the old property factory class with the one where the configuration files are loaded using spring DI. Now this is for live admin page which consists a list of property files, corresponding load time, modification times etc. So I need to find a way to get the load time.Do you think I need to define another constructor with System.currentTimeMillis()? However I need a method which gets it from config object and then I can set it to my view object

Answer (score -1):

For a straightforward way to do this... you can try calling `long before = System.currentTimeMillis()` before the call to retrieve properties, and another `long after = System.currentTimeMillis()` call right after the the properties are retrieved, and seeing the value of the difference, `after - before`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But how do I associate that with my config file?Sorry if its a silly question. I am quite new to java.

Comment: or wrap this logic within an "around" aspect as: getBeforeTime, call execute() method (caputre return _value_), getAfterTime, print out time diff, return _value_